# converse of p → q is q → p . Can we say q →p as p is necessary for q

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In discrete mathematics ,

p → q ( p implies q) , we say p is sufficient for q , this is clear for me

now the converse of p → q  is q → p . In this case , case we say p is necessary for q?

I m little confused of above the statement when I read it  in a discrete mathematics book saying that  q → p means p is necessary for q

if that is true then can we say p → q as q is necessary for p?

Comment: Yep, that's true. If a real-world example helps, consider the statement "clouds are necessary for rain," which is equivalent to "if it is raining, then there must be clouds," or $\text{rain} \implies \text{clouds}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right.  "It is necessary for you to buy a ticket to see the movie" is equivalent to "If you are seeing the movie, then you must have bought a ticket".

It always takes me a little effort to remember which is which. But necessity and sufficiency are key words that get tossed around in mathematical logic, so it's worth getting your head around it.